# Django 1.10 - Formset repopulates deleted item

Tags: django, django-forms

I built up the `Formset` with `can_delete=true`. `Formset` works fine. Problem is repopulating the form, because after the submit, user is redirected on the same form page. What bugs me, is that deleted item still remains in the form, even if it does no longer exists in DB.

**My forms.py:**

```
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'author']


BookFormset = forms.modelformset_factory(
    Book,
    form=BookForm,
    fields=['title', 'description', 'author'],
    can_delete=True,
    extra=1
)
```

**Submit view function:**

```
def submit(request):

    book_formset = BookFormset(request.POST)

    if book_formset.is_valid():
        messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Correct.')
        book_formset.clean()
        book_formset.save()

    else:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Error!')

    context = {
        'book_formset': book_formset,
    }

    return render(request, 'sand/index.html', context)
```

**What I tried**:

In following screens I tried to delete Rabit the Crazy `book`.

**Screen before submit:**

[image]

**Screen after submit:**

[image]

Comment: Note you shouldn't have to call `book_formset.clean()` - this will be done automatically as part of the `book_formset.is_valid()` call.

Comment: Oh, I didnt knew it. Thanks for a tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a successful form submission you should redirect (even if it's to the same URL). This will prevent duplicate submissions. After the redirect, the deleted items will not appear when the formset is reloaded.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def submit(request):
    ...
    if book_formset.is_valid():
        book_formset.save()
        return redirect('/success_url/')
```